# Как через форму отправить несколько GET запросов?

Tags: php, get, forms

Вот у меня есть такая форма :

```
<form  action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="myTextInput"  name="search">
</form>
```

Она передает строку search.php?search=мойзапрос
А мне надо чтобы она еще передавала слово page чтобы получилось search.php?search=мойзапрос&page=1 
???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="myTextInput" name="search">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Нужен был параметр type='hidden' ;